# How to add custom effects to the Swiper slider JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to add a new custom effect to the [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper) slider JavaScript library.

The default Swiper effects are `slide`, `fade`, `cube`, `coverflow` or `flip`
but I want to add my custom effect with and all events. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the `s.effects` object (Effects part) in `swiper.js` and add your own effect property like this:

   ```
   myEffect: {
      setTranslate: function() {
          // your actual animation code goes here
      },
      setTransition: function( duration ) {
          // duration is between 0 and max speed (300 is default)
          // but you can change it in the config object below
          // is called when your swiping starts and ends
      }
   }
   ```
2. To use your new effect do this:

   ```
   var mySwiper = new Swiper( '.swiper-container', {
          // other options …
          // and add this
          effect: “myEffect”
      }
   );
   ```

For more information have a look here:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1497

Comment: it is out of date

Comment: @姚嘉辉 how so? Can you please give us more details on how we should handle it now?

Comment: This link redirects to a 404 page.